# deleted libssl-1.0.0 files by mistake

Tags: data-recovery

I have foolishly deleted the libssl-1.0.0, I have completely deleted the src, lib and all the files that look like (*lib*ssl1*) or something like that!

I tried to use the synaptic package manager to update, or re-install the missing library, no luck, the returned error "E: Internal Error, No file name for libssl1.0.0" appears.

I tired to use apt-get --reinstall, download-only...same error

I included also all packages that have libssl* in their name, no good too.

today the system has been running silly, firefox and flash at chromium aren't working...

anyway I can recover without having to use live CD?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Please paste the exact errors into your question, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

yes,whats yours Ubuntu version - Get those deleted files from similar running machines (if you are using 64-bit machine,make sure other machine also runs with 64-bit) and place it under lib or whatever files you have deleted.That should most likely work.

Sometime back - I deleted files from lib and etc , I was able to fix by copying files into that directory from another running system. It was trail & error trick , but it should work.

Comment: thank you for the effort @lakshmipathi 

I've decided to leave things as they are as after removing ff and re-installing flash my laptop seems to be stable